# Building workspace has encountered a prob in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse-Kepler. When I try to create any CalculatorApplication, I am get this error.

"Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'CalculatorApplication'.
java.lang.NullPointerException"

Can any one help me how to deal with it.!
[Refer Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ7yp.png)